# Oracle weblogic 8.1 plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, oracle, eclipse-plugin, weblogic8.x, legacy-app

Currently I maintain the legacy JavaEE project that run on weblogic 8.1. I would like to update some components of this project.My problem is how to connect weblogic 8.1 in eclipse.(I used eclipse kepler).I found many samples of how to connect weblogic in eclipse but my weblogic version 8.1 is too old and nothing found any eclipse plugin for this server.So give me some ideas or links of old weblogic plugin for eclipse. If eclipse kepler has no weblogic plugin and I can change any eclipse versions.My project run on weblogic 8.1 , oracle database 10g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OEPE 12.1.1.2.2 is the last version with support for WebLogic 8.1 release. It came out right before Kepler went GA so it's certified on Kepler RC3. It should install into the original Kepler release, but will likely not install into Kepler SR1 or SR2. Here is the plugin repository (update site).

http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.1.1.2.2/kepler/repository

If you cannot get that work, the same release is also available for Juno (at every SR level).

http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.1.1.2.2/juno/repository

You can also download pre-packaged Eclipse distributions that include this version of OEPE from the following page.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-121122-1956174.html